# Validate Date Time value on Sqlite before insert / update

Tags: sqlite

as we all know that the correct format for date and time value in sqlite is :

2014-06-18 01:00:00

my question : is there any method to validate date and time value before insert / update on sqlite, maybe when creating table, to make sure date and time data is correct, thanks

Comment: Consider storing timestamps as integers (e.g. seconds since an epoch) and then convert to/from human-readable formats in your code.

Comment: I can't do that, because I use it for winform application, and if I store it as integer, I can't display it for datagridview directly, sorry for my english

Comment: None of the date formats is supposed to be displayed directly.

Comment: sorry, not directly, but correctly, sorry for my bad english again, however thanks for your answer

Answer (score 5):

To enforce that a value is in *any* of the [supported formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), you could just check that some [built-in date function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) is able to parse it:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    MyDate  CHECK (date(MyDate) IS NOT NULL),
    [...]
);
```